# Ternary operator not working with or conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This should be simply but I cant figure it out, all I'm trying to do is add an or condition to my ternary operator, heres the code:

```
{cat === 'electronics' || 'jewelery' ? '' : <Size><b>Size: </b>{size}</Size>}
```

There are 4 categories 2 can have size these 2 cant, now if I remove the or condition like so:

```
{cat === 'jewelery' ? '' : <Size><b>Size: </b>{size}</Size>}
```

This work perfectly fine but then I'll have to add another test when I dont see why || shouldnt be working.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: The way you've written it the second string is being tested for truthiness not equality, you need to explicitly write out all comparisons. `cat === 'electronics' || cat === 'jewelery' ? '' : ...`

Comment: try like this, 
`{(cat === 'electronics' || cat === 'jewelery') ? '' : <Size><b>Size: </b>{size}</Size>}`

Comment: Thank you both, I'd mark either one of these answers as correct but for some reason the questions been linked to an irrelevant one.